# jQuery Cycle Plugin, All images Load and show up at the beginning

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the JQuery cycle plugin, and it runs great.  However, when you first load up the site in ie8, all the images show up on the screen, and then after a few seconds they get set into place and run through the cycles as normal.

I would like them to load up in the background and not show up until it is there turn in the "cycle"

The css looks like:

```
#s1{
float:left;
background-color:#000000;
width:300px;
margin:1;
}

#s2{
float:left;
background-color:#000000;
width:300px;
margin:1;
}
```

the javascript looks like:

```
$('#s1').cycle({
  fx: 'fade',
  timeout: 2500,
  speed: 1000
});

$('#s1').cycle({
  fx: 'fade',
  timeout: 2500,
  speed: 1000
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any knowledge of the markup your using you can try something like this

**css**

```
.imageClass{
    display:none;
}
```

**javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $('imageClass').show();
});
```

That should start the images off hidden, then once the dom is ready show them again, and by that time your plugin should be starting.

Comment: thanks friend, but it this didn't solve my problem.  I will add some more info/code in the above question.

Comment: Ok, I got it!  If anyone ever runs into this problem in the cycle plugin here is documentation to address it: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/faq.html

Answer (score 1):

Remember to add fullstop to var in the Javascript eg  .imageClass

Answer (score 0):

Just put function on load not when documnts ready like this and it works for me:

```
 $(window).load(function(){
      $('#s1').cycle({
      fx: 'fade',
      timeout: 2500,
      speed: 1000
   });

   $('#s1').cycle({
      fx: 'fade',
      timeout: 2500,
      speed: 1000
   });
 });
```

When window will be load img will show up not before that so it cancel the flash